# I want to implement a vector of structs which is in the private part of a templated class

Tags: c++, vector, struct

This is my class called Dictionary I will use it as a hash table so for that I want to have a vector of structs. I have an implementation but at the last part of the code where `vector <node> arr` gives C4430 error. It says: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

Note: This is my first question sorry for the mistakes if any.

```
template <class object>
class Dictionary // Which will be a hash table
{
public:
    explicit Dictionary(const  object & notFound, int size= 101);

    Dictionary(const Dictionary & rhs): ITEM_NOT_FOUND(rhs.ITEM_NOT_FOUND) ,
       arr(rhs.arr), currentSize(rhs.currentSize){}

    enum EntryType { ACTIVE , EMPTY , DELETED };

private:
struct node
{
    object element;
    EntryType info;

    node (const object & e = object(), EntryType i = EMPTY)
        : element( e ), info( i ) {}
};

vector <node> arr;
int currentSize;
const object ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
```

Comment: It probably doesn't recognize vector. You should either write `std::vector` or `using namespace std`.

Comment: Remove the space between vector and the bracket. Also, add `std::`. So, `std::vector<node> arr;` Not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit space doesn't change anything in this case.

Comment: @Estiny I wasn't sure. Parsing around template stuff has been not awesome in the past.

Comment: This code compiles for me with `#include <vector>`, `using std::vector`, and `}; int main() { Dictionary<int> d(5); }` afterwards

Comment: Yes. Guys I did not write 'using namespace std'. So now it works well. Thank you all